# How to localize Google Play and App Store application links?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I'd like to link the users who use my mobile website to my new Android and iOS app, respectively.

To do so, I prepared links to the apps, that will open Google Play on Android and App Store on iOS, if the apps are installed:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/myapp/id123456?l=de
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/myapp/id123456?l=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=en.my.app&hl=de
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=en.my-app&hl=en
```

Notice the language query-string params used at the end of the URLs. In this form, the app pages open in the respective language (English or German) in the browser. However, they have no impact on the language in which the app pages are served in Google Play and App Store.

Is there a way to adjust the links to force Google Play and App Store to show the app pages with a localized interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! Google play store and App Store use the default language set by the user on their device. You cannot force them to change the language for a particular app listing.

Comment: Yep, I just researched this and, indeed, both apps use the language specified in user settings and it doesn't seem to be possible to manipulate it.